# How to properly write a unit test that checks that a path doesn't exist?

Tags: python

I need to write a unit test for a class:

```
import os
class my_class:
  def __init__(self, path):
    assert os.path.exists(path)
```

I want to write a unit test that intentionally passes an incorrect path. Currently, I have this:

```
def unit_test:
  non_existent_path = '/non_existent_path`
  my_class(non_existent_path)
```

and I expect this test to fail, but i don't like my definition `non_existent_path = '/non_existent_path`. Is there a more robust way to specify a path that can never exist?

Comment: Things like [`uuid`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/uuid.html) are useful for creating unique identifiers with a very low chance of collision.

Comment: Since testing uses assertions heavily to determine if the test passes, it's going to be strange and difficult to idiomatically test a non-test that raises `AssertionError`. It might be better if the code did `if not os.path.exists(...): raise RuntimeError` or something.

Answer (score 2):

This seems like a textbook use case for [`unittest.mock.patch`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.patch), instead of trying use real data about the environment/filesystem, etc.

```
from unittest.mock import patch
from unittest import TestCase

from my_mod import MyClass

class TestMyClass(TestCase):
    def test_init_bad_path(self):
        with patch("os.path.exists") as path_exists:
            path_exists.return_value = False
            with self.assertRaises(AssertionError):
                MyClass("path")

    def test_init_good_path(self):
        with patch("os.path.exists") as path_exists:
            path_exists.return_value = True
            inst = MyClass("path")
        ... some other assertions about `inst` I guess
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`tempfile`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tempfile.html#tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile) to generate a random safe path that does not exist. Note the usage of `delete = True` in calling `tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile()`.

```py
import tempfile
from pathlib import Path

def get_random_nonexisting_path():
    temp_path = tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(delete=True)
    return temp_path.file.name

random_path = get_random_nonexisting_path()
print(f"{random_path = }")
print(f"{Path(random_path).exists() = }")
```

prints

```
random_path = '/var/folders/9b/by8fs6g565gdlhxgs8lkf3200000gq/T/tmp9btpp5ko'
Path(random_path).exists() = False
```

Comment: This creates a file, isnt that the opposite of what the question is?

Comment: Sorry. Just updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you're fine with coming  up with programmatically, here is a modified version of [`tempfile`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tempfile.html) private [`_RandomNameSequence`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/6c13e13b13bebfdde8ad4019536499820cdfc926/Lib/tempfile.py#L132-L154) class which does that:

```
import os
import random
import tempfile


def non_existent_file(directory=None):
    characters = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789_"

    rng = random.Random()
    # default to the users temp directory if no directory is specified
    target_dir = directory or tempfile.gettempdir()

    # keep looping till we find a path that doesnt exist
    while True:
        random_letters = "".join(rng.choices(characters, k=8))
        target = os.path.join(target_dir, random_letters)
        if not os.path.exists(target):
            return target


def test_non_exists():
    random_path = non_existent_file()

    assert not os.path.exists(random_path)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Faker` library

```
from faker import Faker
fake = Faker()
...
    Faker.seed(0)
    fake_file_path = fake.file_path(3)
```

It will generate fake path with 3 depths

> '/back/show/bit/force.avi'

You can find details here
Faker [file_path](https://faker.readthedocs.io/en/master/providers/faker.providers.file.html)

Comment: well, *incredibly low chance* since it uses random words, but doesnt look like [`file_path`](https://github.com/joke2k/faker/blob/7acf71854abae88323a433898f3218bebd39448f/faker/providers/file/__init__.py#L277-L281) actually checks if the file exists.

Comment: @SeanBreckenridge I don't think that's the purpose of faker, so I would change the answer to reflect this - and maybe add a check to continue generating a `file_path` until one that doesn't exist is returned

Comment: It only generates random file path